# Raritan Dominion DKX2-464 shows "No video from target server" on remote access

Tags: java, kvm-switch, remote-connection, jre

I have bought a used KVM Raritan Dominion KX2-464 device (with firmware 2.7.0.5.2183). Is is out of the support duration. I can connect PCs over CIM devices and can see the screen image, when I connect a screen on the local console.

I can also start the MPC (multi-platform client - version 7.0.3.5.62) and connect. It shows "No video from target server" in the middle of the remote screen area, keyboard strokes are received on the remote PC, however.

I tried high (1920x1080) and low (800x600) screen resolutions. I tried connecting VGA-CIMs and HDMI-CIMs. I tried different 32-bit and 64-bit JRE versions. (1.5 gives a ClassNotFoundError, when trying to start MPC, the higher ones seem to work up to the aforementioned "No video from target server"). I tried to import the self-signed certificate generated by the Raritan device into Windows and I get no error messages for it (when using the console with the browser or when starting MPC), but it could be that the video connection is separate?

I even installed an old Firefox version and can run MPC over the Java Applets instead of Java Webstart. Both have the same error.

The PC is running Windows 10; same result with Windows 7 client PC.

[image: Displayed image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that the cable connection from the CIM to the Dominion KX II was of bad quality.

For the local connection to a directly attached screen the Dominion presumably just switches the analog signal. However, for a remote connection it tries to grab the screen and convert it to a digital signal.

The internal screen grabber of the Dominion KX II probably has higher requirements of the signal quality than the locally attached screen, that is why only the remote connection did not work.

With a better cable connection to the CIM also the remote connections started to work.

Comment: how did you get this to work since java support has been dropped? What version of firefox and what OS are you using? I am using firefox 48 32 bit and got java plugin enabled but still not working for me...please share how you got this to work for you please...thanks

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/1719950/1004573

Comment: It is possible to start from older versions of Firefox with deactivated update that still support Java Plugins. The more simple way is to use Java Web Start and start the remote screen without a browser (done it with Windows 7 and 10). It is also alternatively working with ActiveX and Internet Explorer from Windows 7 (not sure about newer Windows versions). So 3 working ways to start it with Firefox the most hasslesome.