# Raritan KVM KX2 won't work because of java issue with firefox 48 on windows 10

Tags: firefox, java, kvm-switch

I have been able to get past many obstacles already to even get to where am at. I was able to install firefox 48 32-bit on windows 10 pro OS. I also installed java and enabled java on firefox.

Was able to access the DKX2 GUI but just can not use the remote access KVM still even with java enabled and all

What do i need to do to get this to work? Will appreciate your help greatly. Thanks

```
Device Name: DominionKX2-232
Firmware: 2.7.0.5.2183
Device Model: DKX2-232
```

Please see below screenshots

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

UPDATES:

[image]

Comment: Try, if it works with WebStart (if not then also starting from Firefox won't work). When testing, I created a self-signed certificate on the Dominion and imported it into the Windows certificate store. That could have made a difference. Is the local connection to the port working (screen and keyboard attached to the Dominion directly)? Dual-VM is with two screens? This I did not try so far.

Comment: what is webstart? also i added website on exception list so it trusts my ssl cert...i am using self signed also that expires in 10 years from now..how did you import into the windows certificate store? steps will be appreciated

Comment: For putting a certificate into Windows (it has nothing to do with the certificate store of the browser) look here for example: https://superuser.com/questions/1315820/how-to-make-chrome-trust-windows-system-root-ca-certificate  WebStart is a way to start Java programs from command line. On Windows it is the javaws.exe in the Java directory. They deprecated it with some Java version recently, but yours should have it. You should download the multi platform client from the Raritan support page. I had to slightly change the Dominion .bat file starting javaws to point to the correct Java directory

Comment: You can also try Internet Explorer with Active X. It definitely works with Windows 7 (and simpler than Firefox/Java, no installation necessary), not sure about the steps for Windows 10.

Comment: i have microsoft edge as you know windows 10 forces update..and edge is just like crhome and latest firefox and blocks java also..any links or videos to check for the activex? using windows 10 pro

Comment: check `UPDATES` in question..i added screenshot, so i imported the cert into windows now..do i need to restart the computer to take effect? i still get insecure cert warning so not sure i need to restart computer..i just imported using `certlm` program...is this good enough?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136133/discussion-between-uberrebu-and-sebastian).

Comment: Certificate looks good so far, but I am not sure, there are different certificate stores as you see for purpose and for scope (computer / user?); I tried with all that would take the certificate. The insecure cert warning is from Firefox? Then it is unrelated.

Comment: I have not further tried ActiveX with Windows 10. Edge has an IE mode: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode

Comment: which browser works for you? firefox? we can focus on firefox for now since i just got one thing left to have it work..rather than starting from scratch with explorer

Comment: can you share link on how to use webstart with this? because am not sure how webstart will work with raritan dkx2...what commands do i use and is it a GUI program? thanks

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javaws.html javaws is a command line program, which starts a packaged Java program. The MPC program itself has a GUI and it looks basically the same as the web interface. After installing the MPC there already is a short script (4 lines?) with file extension .bat starting javaws. Just make sure that it finds the correct javaws (there could be several versions of Java be installed on your system) and that your classpath environment variable is set up.

Comment: "and latest firefox and blocks java also" - But they also provide a mechanism to allow the content.  Java content hasn't been removed from any browser to my knowledge.

Comment: tried internet explorer and. it worked...did not know the browser was on my computer until i searched the full name

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using internet explorer 11 on windows 10. Did not realize this still comes with Windows 10; thought microsoft edge replaced it, but it just worked without having to do anything at all on Internet Explorer browser

Comment: IE11 will be removed from all supported versions of Windows 10 and Windows 11 in June 2022.